# CSOM 2013 error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary

Tags: csom

I'm using this code to loop columns of a SharePoint 2013 List.

```
    currentContext.Load(currentList.Fields);
    currentContext.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (Field f in currentList.Fields) {

    }
```

No problem with normal columns. But, when I arrive to a lookup column I have this error:

> "Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'
>   to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field'."

I found for example this [discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4649a844-3fb0-4e3f-8988-4f6a762a9455/client-object-model-unhandled-exception-systeminvalidcastexception-unable-to-cast-object-of?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: I found that error occours on taxonomy fields... but why!?

Answer (score 1):

This issue came when we were working with *TaxonomyFieldValue* fields. For us changing references was not an option. This helped:

```
TaxonomyItem dummy = new TaxonomyItem(web.Context, null);
```

It will force program to load adequate libraries forcing correct type in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and updating the references fixed it for me.  [This question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83803/looping-retrieved-items-throws-an-invalidcastexception) helped me figure it out.

I went from version 14 of "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client" and "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime" to version 16 and no longer had the error.

[Latest client download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=35585)